# Dock is appearing too soon

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen

I'm using *Remote Desktop* app on the full screen and when I get my mouse too close to the bottom of the screen (in orders to interact with remote system), the *Dock* is shown.

[image: macOS Dock, show/hide]

The mouse pointer (annotated below) is not even close to the *Dock* edge or icons and the bar is already showing up.

[image: macOS Dock, show/hide]

So there is no way I can access the bottom icons on the remote machine.

How do I change Dock behaviour, so it's not so aggressive when it comes to appearing? Or disable it in the full-screen mode completely?

Answer (score 3):

System Preferences application allows you to change the behavior of the Dock. The Dock preferences pane is shown below.

[image: 99]

I would suggest moving the dock to the left or right side of the screen.

Comment: Pretty weird, but when I've set it to the right, it's showing up (on the right side), but only when I move my mouse to the bottom, not to the right. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: @kenorb: What version of macOS are you using? What version of Microsoft Remote Desktop? I am using macOS 10.13.3 and Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.43. I tested and I am not having the problem you describe.

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.12.6 with MRD v8.0.5. From my experience, my system always behaves differently. I'm planning to install High Sierra over the weekend anyway on the new SSD.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The same UX flaw exists on the left and right sides of the screen.